# Pug - Cannot read property 'length' of undefined when trying to iterate through json objects

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, pug

I'm trying to display all of the results retrieved via mongoose from my database on my webpage but I keep getting "`Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`" in my `index.pug` file where I've written my `each` loop to iterate through the returned cursor of `json` objects so I can display them. I'm new to express, mongoose, and pug so I'm having trouble figuring out my mistake.

Here is a snippet of my `index.pug` file:

```
section(class="get")
h3 Get Data
a(href="/get-data") LOAD DATA
div
  each val in items
    article(class="item")
      div Title: #{val.title}
      div Content: #{val.content}
      div Author: #{val.author}
      div ID: #{val._id}
```

where `items` should be passed in by mongoose from the below `express.js` snippet of my `index.js` file:

```
router.get('/get-data', function(req, res, next) {
  // Use mongoose to find data from database
  UserData.find()
     .then(function(doc) {
       res.render('index', {items: doc});
     });
});
```

When I try to load the webpage I'm met with this error:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

With details pointing to the line of my each loop:

```
21|     a(href="/get-data") LOAD DATA
22|     div
23|  >    each val in items
24|         article(class="item")
25|           div Title: #{val.title}
26|           div Content: #{val.content}
```

Any insight into this issue would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like your `items` array is `undefined`. Can you add `console.log(doc)` inside the ```GET /get-data``` method and reproduce behavior (and see if the log works)?

Comment: @oneturkmen I've inserted that line right before the res.render() call. Where should I expect to see the output?

Comment: Should be on your console/terminal (wherever you do `npm start` or `node server.js`)

Comment: @oneturkmen I'm assuming I'm looking for a json output to the console? However, all I'm getting is some GET requests that look like this: GET / 500 266.035 ms - 3051
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 1.985 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 0.511 ms - -

Comment: And some warnings about unhandled promise rejections, which I don't understand

Comment: well, for some reason you are getting 500 code, which you should fix first

Comment: Also, in some case, your `items` array may be empty. Add the following right above `each val in items` line: `if posts`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180384/discussion-between-oneturkmen-and-mcfizz).

Answer (score 3):

I never had chance to find out what is actually causing this problem. I will update my answer once I found out the reason. But this is the fix.

What I feel is that pug tries to use "items" when it is not initialised. It will work once it gets initialised in subsequent renders. So try adding the conditional operator like this

```
     a(href="/get-data") LOAD DATA
     div
        each val in items ? items : [] 
          article(class="item")
            div Title: #{val.title}
            div Content: #{val.content}
```

This will simply not cause error when pug tries to render the page with undefined items.

I will update my answer once I found out the reason behind this. Hope my duct tape solution gets job done for you.

Comment: Did solved for me too. Later I tried to remove it and re-start the node server and worked as well. Seems like I was forgetting to stop the server and restarting it.

Answer (score 0):

You must have some issue when you are querying the database, you must check if you the query succeeded before using the result that is retrieved. Because you are getting your result using `Promise` you can add a `catch` after a then to catch any error that will be thrown

```
router.get('/get-data', function(req, res, next) {
  // Use mongoose to find data from database
    UserData.find({})
        .then(function(doc) {
           res.render('index', {items: doc});
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
});
```